# Does collection.mutable.HashMap have an efficient size method?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I am using `collection.mutable.Map` which defaults to `collection.mutable.HashMap`. I need to keep track of the number of items in that map, so I would like to know whether this class already implements a fast `size` response, which would free me from having to track it myself.

Is this related to the `useSizeMap` method? Unfortunately the documentation of this method is so vague, it is completely useless to determine anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of `collection.mutable.HashMap` is stored as an `Int` that is incremented/decremented  according to add/remove methods, so calling the `size` method should be instantaneous ( O(1) ). You can see it yourself on the [source code of `HashTable`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/HashTable.scala), which `HashMap` inherits from.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I went to the source from the IDE, somehow didn't spot the size method in the first place, so I wasn't sure. Then went with force-entry in the step debugger to see what it's doing and indeed saw the forward to `tableSize`. So that has nothing to do with `useSizeMap`.

Comment: No, the `useSizeMap` is used (as far as i known) to resize the hash table. Again, there's more info on the source code about the size maps.